# Compare last 2 elements in an array

Tags: reactjs

I want to compare elements in an array. The values of the array is getting from selecting the checkbox in a grid.I want to compare last 2 selected element's data in the array. For example my array is like on first selection
`let arr = [{aID:5, name: "trt", address:"tyuy", type:"ttype"}].`
That time there is no need of comparison. On second checkbox selection

```
arr=[{aID:5, name: "trt", address:"tyuy", type:"ttype"},
{aID:6, name: "trt", address:"thyr", type:"ttype"},
]
```

compare 2 elements type and name be same, my code is like,

```
for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
      for (let k = i + 1; k < selected.length; k++) {
          if ((selected[i].type === selected[k].type) &&(selected[i].name === selected[k].name)) {
            this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: e, selectedRecords: selected })
          }
          else{
            return message.warning("Select lien with same type and Name.")
          }
      }
      if(selected.length === 1){
      this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: e, selectedRecords: selected })
      }
```

This code works perfectly on 2 selection but the isssue is starts from 3rd selection on third selction we selct different type and name row it also given checked as I per my code. I want to compare  last 2 elements like,

```
let arr =[{aID:5, name: "trt", address:"tyuy", type:"ttype"},
{aID:6, name: "trt", address:"thyr", type:"ttype"},
{aID:6, name: "gdg", address:"thyr", type:"ptype"},
]
```

expected result is not show the selection of the checkbox of different type and name and also show the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. In case of comparing only two elements**

```
let arr=[{aID:5, name: "trt", address:"tyuy", type:"ttype"},
  {aID:6, name: "trt", address:"thyr", type:"ttype"},
  ]

  if(arr.length > 1){
    if(arr[arr.length-1].type === arr[arr.length-2].type && arr[arr.length-1].name === arr[arr.length-2].name){
        //code if true
    }else{

    }
  }
```

**2. In other cases, use the filter function of arrays**

```
let arr=[{aID:5, name: "trt", address:"tyuy", type:"ttype"},
      {aID:6, name: "trt", address:"thyr", type:"ttype"},
      {aID:7, name: "trt", address:"thyr", type:"ttype"},
      {aID:8, name: "trt", address:"thyr", type:"ttype"},
      {aID:9, name: "trt", address:"thyr", type:"ttype"},
      {aID:10, name: "trt", address:"thyr", type:"ttype"},
      ]

arr.map(item =>{
  let arr_ = array.filter(ig =>ig.name === item.name && ig.type === item.type)
  //now print all array elements wich have the same name and type as item
  //if you want to know if they all have the same name and type values, just check length like this
  if(arr_.length === arr.length){
    //code here
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another doubt If I select all checkbox  in that case also need to check. Can you help me?

Comment: It can work. This method just compare the last two inputs of an array

Comment: It is not like that I said, select one by one . I have an option Selectall which clicking that checkbox all the checkbox get selected

Comment: So you want to know how you can compare more than 2 elements in case checkAll is clicked?

Comment: yes. I want to know that case also or compare each element in an array